# C++ unordered_set<insert function> return value

Tags: c++, stl, unordered-set

I am trying to check return value of unordered_set's insert() function, but stuck with below error:

```
unordered_set<int> t;
t.insert(1);
t.insert(2);
t.insert(3);
t.insert(4);
std::unordered_set<int>::iterator it = t.insert(1); **//Error**
cout<<"size of t="<<t.size()<<endl;
```

**Error-->conversion from 'std::pair<std::__detail::_Node_iterator<int, true, false>, bool>' to non-scalar type 'std::unordered_set::iterator {aka std::__detail::_Node_iterator<int, true, false>}' requested**

-->Insert function should send a empty iterator if the insert function is not successful, but I am unable to declare the proper iterator for return value of insert function.
-->What should be the proper type of unordered_set iterator for insert function in this case?

Comment: See [`std::unordered_set::insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/insert), the return is not an iterator, but a`pair<iterator, bool>`.

Comment: have you checked with auto ? auto does the type deduction in most compile time types

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your understanding of the return value of unordered_set::insert is incorrect.

> Returns a pair consisting of an iterator to the inserted element (or
> to the element that prevented the insertion) and a bool denoting
> whether the insertion took place.

(from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/insert))

So the correct declaration is

```
std::pair<std::unordered_set<int>::iterator, bool> it = t.insert(1);
```

but really (assuming you have C++11) it's a lot easier to write

```
auto it = t.insert(1);
```

If you are only interested in the returned iterator, then you could also write

```
std::unordered_set<int>::iterator it = t.insert(1).first;
```

or again using auto

```
auto it = t.insert(1).first;
```

Comment: How to validate the it1 iterator please, below comparison is not working.
       auto it1 = n.insert(1).first;
 if(it1 == n.end())
 {
  cout<<"it1 unsuccessful"<<endl;
 }

Comment: @SantoshSahu Did you read my quote? `a bool denoting whether the insertion took place` so you can test that like this `auto it = n.insert(1); if (!it.second) cout<<"unsuccessful"<<endl;`